# Timesheet MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a working timecard in `MySQL`, but I have no way of talleying times using `VIEW`s or `FUNCTION`s. I'd like to use a `MySQL` function call such as `getTodaysHours (user CHAR(45))` to return the user's hours for the day (including hours since punch in). Problem is I don't know how to perform the math inside of a FUNCTION.

Here is my table:

[image: Time Sheet]

And here is my "in trouble" procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getTodaysHours`(OUT hours INT, IN user CHAR(45))
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(timestamp) FROM info
  WHERE DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp-25200) )=CURDATE() AND
  fullname=user
  ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
END
```

Obviously `SUM()` is not what I want to use, but I wanted the rest to work.

Comment: So it would appear that ericfoss has checked in twice in a row, with no intervening check out. So did he work `131029200` to `1319610596`? Or from `1319587159` to `139610596`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people can clock in and out multiple times on the same day this will be very difficult to do with only a single pure SQL statement with the database structure you have showing above.

If its know that you can only check in / out once per day here is something that would work

```
SELECT COALESCE(out.timestamp, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) - in.timestamp
FROM info in
LEFT OUTER JOIN info out on in.fullname = out.fullname
WHERE in.inout = 'in'
AND out.inout = 'out'
AND DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(in.timestamp),CURDATE()) = 0
AND DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(out.timestamp),CURDATE()) = 0
```

If you add a column that tracks pairs of ins/outs it would become easy to compare since you will be able to join on that column.  The way it is now you would have to do a correlated sub-select to find the next closest out after the in.

All in all, you should probably make this procedural since single SQL statements won't return decent errors in the case the data doesn't conform to the query's expectation (the two ins now outs case above)

Comment: It needs to support multiple ins and outs and report days that have odd numbers of punches. The odd punches is easy with a count() != even, but on a single day the odd punch means he/she is still working and all math needs to respond accordingly. The possible outputs are 0, start-end, and start-current. all errors return 0.